# R dplyr::mutate using ifelse and %in% cannot create a factor (In mutate_impl: binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to code a new factor column with `mutate` depending on the value of an existing column, grouping on yet another column, using `dplyr`, and all of that seems fairly straightforward but for some reason R isn't happy with that and keeps raising warnings and creating a character column instead of factor...

I could obviously just leave it like that and add a line using `df$col <- factor(df$col)`, but I'd like to understand what's wrong with my code and correct it so it works directly within `mutate`.

Here is a MWE that reproduces the error on both the computers I have access to:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8),
  StimLabel = factor(c("NoLabelFeedback","NoLabelFeedback",
                       "NoLabelFeedback","NoLabelFeedback",
                       "Saldie","Gatoo",
                       "Gatoo","Saldie",
                       "NoLabelFeedback","NoLabelFeedback",
                       "NoLabelFeedback","NoLabelFeedback",
                       "Saldie","Gatoo",
                       "Gatoo","Saldie"))
)

df <- df %>% group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(Condition = factor(ifelse("NoLabelFeedback" %in% StimLabel,"NoLabel","Label")))
```

Edit: My problem here is stated in the title: I'm getting a coercion warning. The output produced by R is just fine, except for the fact that `Condition` is a `character` column, not `factor`.

What I'm trying to do exactly is, if any of the values in `StimLabel` for a subject is `"NoLabelFeedback"`, then set the value of `Condition` to `"NoLabel"` for the subject. In practice, I'm using `%in%` as for each subject either all or none of the values for `StimLabel` will be `"NoLabelFeedback"`, and it felt to me that this way R would have less tests to conduct half of the time as it would stop checking the dataframe after the first test. If anyone has an idea on how to make it better I'm up for it, but this really isn't the point of this question.

Comment: @akrun I'm fairly sure that's not the point, as before trying to use `group_by` and `mutate` to do this on the whole dataset, I was doing the exact same thing when importing each subject's data and it worked fine. The point here is really to say, for each subject, if one of the values for `StimLabel` is `"NoLabelFeedback"`. Otherwise I would just use `==` instead of `%in%`...

Comment: @akrun how would you use `if/else` in that case? Can you develop, as I'm not sure how it would work, and would totally do it if it was a better or quicker way of doing it.

Comment: In that case `df %>% group_by(Subject) %>%  mutate(Condition = factor(if("NoLabelFeedback" %in% StimLabel) "NoLabel" else "Label", levels = c("NoLabel", "Label")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you're declaring a factor variable while using an `ifelse` function. R won't know the factor *levels* this way. The following code works:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8),
  StimLabel = factor(c("NoLabelFeedback","NoLabelFeedback",
                       "NoLabelFeedback","NoLabelFeedback",
                       "Saldie","Gatoo",
                       "Gatoo","Saldie",
                       "NoLabelFeedback","NoLabelFeedback",
                       "NoLabelFeedback","NoLabelFeedback",
                       "Saldie","Gatoo",
                       "Gatoo","Saldie"))
)

df2 <- df %>% group_by(Subject) %>%
    mutate(Condition = factor(ifelse("NoLabelFeedback" %in% StimLabel,
                                     "NoLabel","Label"),
                              levels = c("NoLabel","Label")))
```

Comment: That indeed solved the problem! I find it weird that R can't guess levels for a factor on the go, but now that I know it I'll just declare my levels properly.

Comment: @ArthurSpoon You are applying `factor` to each group. The problem is that each group has different levels and so they cannot be coherently combined, unless they are coerced to `character`. You should coerce to factor after grouping, which is clearer and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight improvement in efficiency if we use `if/else`

```
df %>%
   group_by(Subject) %>%
   mutate(Condition = factor(if("NoLabelFeedback" %in% StimLabel) "NoLabel" else "Label",
                                  levels = c("NoLabel", "Label")))
```

But, if we go with `data.table` assignment, it would be faster

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(Subject = rep(1:1e5, each = 30),
               StimLabel = sample(c("NoLabelFeedback","Saldie","Gatoo"),
                      1e5*30, replace = TRUE))


system.time({
  r1 <- df %>%
             group_by(Subject) %>%
             mutate(Condition = factor(if("NoLabelFeedback" %in% StimLabel) "NoLabel"
                        else "Label", levels = c("NoLabel", "Label")))
   })
 # user  system elapsed 
 #  8.55    0.00    8.58 




system.time({
   r2 <- df %>% group_by(Subject) %>%
    mutate(Condition = factor(ifelse("NoLabelFeedback" %in% StimLabel,
                                     "NoLabel","Label"),
                              levels = c("NoLabel","Label")))
}) 
#user  system elapsed 
#   9.46    0.00    9.62
```

using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
system.time({

     setDT(df)[, Condition := factor(if("NoLabelFeedback" %in% StimLabel) "NoLabel"
      else "Label", levels = c("NoLabel", "Label")), Subject]

})
# user  system elapsed 
#   1.48    0.02    1.50 

identical(df$Condition, r1$Condition)
#[1] TRUE
```